# Tensorflow's Neurons

Tags: tensorflow

I want to be able to make inferential analysis on my neural network by accessing the weights and making decision based on what I've found. In other words, If I've got my list of weights of a particular neuron in a hidden layer, then I want to be able to manipulate that neuron in any way I want. I want to mess with the Neuron's output. I'm using tensorflow for my neural network.

Comment: just play polygon window to the neurons

Comment: My neurons are now dancing, what do?